# Form validation in React final form not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-final-form, adminlte

I am creating registration form for one of my project using react final form. Everything is working fine, but the blocker is that validation message is not displayed as expected.

Below is my code,

```
/** @format */

// CSS Section

// Component Section
import React from 'react';
import { Field, Form } from 'react-final-form';
import { combineValidators, isRequired } from 'revalidate';

function PatientCreation() {
    // React Final Form's onSubmit event handler.
    const onSubmit = (values: any) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(values));
    };

    const validate = combineValidators({
        name1: isRequired({ message: 'Name is required' }),
        age: isRequired({ message: 'Age is required' }),
        phone: isRequired({ message: 'Phone number needed' }),
    });
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='content-wrapper'>
                <div className='content-header'>
                    <div className='container-fluid'>
                        <div className='row mb-2'>
                            <div className='col-sm-6'>
                                <h1 className='m-0'>Patient Creation</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='row mb-2'>
                            <div className='col-md-6'>
                                <Form
                                    onSubmit={onSubmit}
                                    validate={validate}
                                    render={({ handleSubmit, invalid, pristine }) => (
                                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                            <div className='form-group'>
                                                <label htmlFor='name1'>Name</label>
                                                <Field
                                                    name='name1'
                                                    className='form-control'
                                                    component='input'
                                                    placeholder='Name'
                                                />
                                            </div>
                                            <div className='form-group'>
                                                <label htmlFor='age'>Age</label>
                                                <Field
                                                    name='age'
                                                    className='form-control'
                                                    component='input'
                                                    placeholder='Age'></Field>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className='form-group'>
                                                <label htmlFor='phone'>Phone</label>
                                                <Field name='phone'>
                                                    {({ input, meta }) => (
                                                        <div>
                                                            <input
                                                                type='text'
                                                                className='form-control'
                                                                {...input}
                                                                placeholder='Phone'
                                                            />
                                                            {meta.touched && meta.error && (
                                                                <span>{meta.error}</span>
                                                            )}
                                                        </div>
                                                    )}
                                                </Field>
                                            </div>
                                            <button
                                                type='submit'
                                                className='btn btn-block btn-success'>
                                                Submit
                                            </button>
                                        </form>
                                    )}
                                />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default PatientCreation;
```

I am using the adminLTE-3 component. My form validation should work similar to this https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/pages/forms/validation.html

As I recently started to work on react and adminLTE-3. I came across many links, but I could not find the proper solution. I need to resolve this as soon as possible due to my task deadline.

Any quick help is really appreciable. Thanks in advance.

**Note: For now I have included the validation for phone text box for testing purpose.**

Comment: Try meta.modified instead of meta.touched. That'll work

Comment: I tried meta.modified instead of meta.touched. It is working as before, but error message is not displayed in red as displayed in adminLTE. Any suggestion?

Comment: Use css for that. Write classname in span.